# In CakePHP 3.0 what is the best way to implement a Controller and Function that doesn't follow CakePHP naming conventions?

Tags: php, android, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

Android has a naming convention for its App Links verification that is not allowed in CakePhP.  Android forces your App Links verification to be as follows:

> www.exampledomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json/

PhP won't allow a class named ".WellKnownController", nor a function named "assetlinks.json".  So how do I make my CakePhP 3.0 website respond to this POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't attempt to change CakePHP's naming conventions, [define routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) instead. For example:-

```
$routes->connect(
    '/.well-known/:action', 
    ['controller' => 'WellKnowns']
);
```

To handle the `json` extentensions you can enable them like this:-

```
Router::extensions(['json']);
```

Comment: OK your suggestion didn't work for me verbatim, but after you pointed me in the right direction to read, research and trial and error, I've discovered that this works for me in router.php:  
Router::connect(
    '/.well-known/assetlinks.json', 
    ['controller' => 'WellKnown', 'action' => 'assetlinksjson']
);

Answer (score 1):

Your class and method names should still be as per CakePHP conventions. You can use [url routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) to route any url to any controller action you want.